# New to jquery. Starts with selector breaks the code. what's is wrong?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Thanks for the help. I'm trying to use a jQuery selector to watch for a click on a group of elements, that start with particular characters. I have come up with the following code, but I must be missing something. If I hard code the ID (ie. $("#test_1")...), the code works:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="parentcontainer">
        <div id="test_1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#statusbar").text("Ready");
        $("#parentcontainer").click(function(){alert("parent clicked");});
        $("#btnaddelement").click(function(){alert("Add Button Clicked");});
        $("[name^='test_']").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();
        alert("Child Clicked");});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just to add to yincheng's comment. Do not use `$(window).load`. Use `$(document).ready(function(){..});` or better yet the handy shortcut version `$(function(){...});`. These fire as soon as the DOM is ready to manipulate, making your page more responsive than if you wait for everything to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting on `$("[name^='test_']")` which will give you elements who have a `name` attribute that start with `test_`. You need to select on `$("[id^='test_']")` for elements with an `id` that start with `test_`. That is one example of what you are getting with your hard-coded success of `$('#test_1')` -- an element whose `id` attribute is `test_1`.

Also, be aware if you are not already that xpath is the language used for selectors, so you can do all kinds of incredible selection if you become familiar with it.

Comment: Wow, that worked, Thanks Buddy. I will research xpath as well. Thank You.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Glad I could help. Good luck building your jQuery skills. They are quite helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you missed something. Change the div's attribute `id` to `name` will work

`<div name="test_1"></div>`

Actually, `class` was used more frequently.

And there are an opinion I want to improve the code.

Try to use the jquery's `$(document).ready` instead of DOM's `load`. Because `load` will wait for all the sources to be loaded compeletely before the js code can be executed, for example, all the photos are downloading ok.

I hope this help!

Comment: Changing the HTML to suit the code is backwards, Also, item `(2)` is just wrong. jQuery's `stopPropagation()` (which is the one used here) works fine in all browsers. They were jQuery click events, not native browser events.

Comment: For item1, I know your meaning, but I intend to express that use `$("#id")` is fine with id attribute, which needs not the complex selector. For item2, thank you for your reminding!

Comment: A starts-with (specified in question) will always require what you call a complex operator, but yes your first part was correct in that way. I suggest you alter your question to remove the incorrect part (so I can remove my downvote).